# How to check the change betweent two code versions with a static checking tool?

Tags: svn

How to check the change betweent two code versions with a static checking tool ?
For example, the static checking tool is FlexPMD; the version management tools is svn. When part of the changes between the two versions using svn find out, how to use FlexPMD check the part of changed.
Or is exist directly contains the version control and static checking tool ?

Comment: So, to summarize, you're trying to call a magical tool that spots problems on only _parts_ of your code base, so that you can spot problems with individual check-ins?

Comment: Yes,I hope use some tool automatable check it.